# ¿Cómo hago la suma de todos los valores de la fila x de una matriz?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

De momento tengo hasta este punto, no se si esta bien, a ver si me podéis ayudar

```
def SumarFila(matriu, x):
    suma=0
    for i in range(len(matriu)):
        for j in range(len(matriu[i])):
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema de tu código es que tú haces dos for, el primero es para obtener la longitud de la fila X y luego recorres cada valor. El problema es que el primer for se va a repetir tantas veces como posiciones tenga la matriz en la fila X. Y, por tanto, se van a sumar el mismo número len(x) veces.

```py
def SumarFila(matriu, x):
    suma=0
    # Recorres la matriz de la fila x desde la posición 0 hasta la última -1
    for i in range(len(matriu[x])):
        # Luego sumas el valor de la posición [x][i]
        suma += matriu[x][i]

    return suma
```

Comment: Agregale una explicacion a la respuesta, para que entienda porque no le sale

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función `sum()` [documentacion oficial de python sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) de python que suma todos los elementos de un iterable, ejemplo:

```
matriz = [[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9]]

def sumar_fila(matriz, fila):
    return sum(matriz[fila])

sumar_fila(matriz, 1)
```

**Salida:** `15`

En este caso, le pasamos la matriz que queremos sumar la fila, y después la fila seleccionada como segundo parametro. Mediante indice se accede a dicha fila de la matriz y se suman los elementos con `sum()`